# Windows 8 app - MediaElement not playing ".wmv" files

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have an issue with `MediaElement` in my Win8 app - when I try to play some ".wmv" files from local library it very often (not always) throws `MediaFailed` and I get the error

> MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT - 0xC00D36C4

which means

> Either the video codec or the audio codec is unsupported, or one of
>   the streams in a video file is corrupted. This content may not be
>   supported.

The problem is *not* that files are corrupted (I can play them with Windows Media Player). Here's the code I use to set `MediaElement`:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
    StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        using (IRandomAccessStream ras = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            me.SetSource(ras, file.ContentType);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what's wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: which codecs do these .wmv files use? (audio&video)

Comment: I don't know, all were downloaded from http://channel9.msdn.com/ , I thought `MediaElement`and Windows Media Player used the same engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are closing the stream prior to playing it. Therefore this code:

```
if (file != null)
{
    using (IRandomAccessStream ras = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        me.SetSource(ras, file.ContentType);
    }
    // The stream is now closed! How can it be played!?
}
```

should be changed to not have the `using` block:

```
if (file != null)
{
    IRandomAccessStream ras = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    me.SetSource(ras, file.ContentType);
}
```

I did try the second block of code above on some channel 9 videos (both mid and high quality wmv files) and my app played them successfully.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I've searched quite some time on this one. Thanks!!