# 'MediaElement.SetSource()' isn't updating consistently

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, mediaelement

My program should play a video when the user presses the 'Play' button. While it normally does this, the very first time they press the 'Play' button nothing will happen.

I have traced this bug back to the following code, which sets my MediaElement 'VideoPlayer':

```
public void playVideo_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  setUpVideo();
  VideoPlayer.Play();
}

public async void setUpVideo()
{
  if(vm == null) return;
  StorageFile videoFile = vm.videoFile;

  if (videoFile == null || !videoFile.ContentType.Equals("video/mp4")) return;

    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await videoFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
      VideoPlayer.SetSource(fileStream, videoFile.ContentType);
    }
}
```

The culprit seems to be the 'SetSource()' method at the end. The only variable that changes from the first click of 'Play' to the next is the variable 'VideoPlayer.PlayToSource', which is changed from null to a real value.

(As a side note, the variable 'VideoPlayer.CurrentState' also changes from 'Closed' to 'Opening' but resets itself to 'Closed' before the second click. Only 'PlayToSource' changes the functionality.)

I figured that I could do a quick-fix by doing this in my first method:

```
  setUpVideo();
  setUpVideo();
  VideoPlayer.Play();
```

Not great code but it ought to set things straight, right? Nope! This causes a NullReferenceException. On the second call to 'setUpVideo()' I find that 'PlayToSource' still has a value and 'VideoPlayer.CurrentState' is still set to 'Opening'... which somehow triggers the NullReferenceException.

I'm expecting the solution to be one of the following things:

1.) Set 'VideoPlayer.PlayToSource' on the first click before calling 'SetSource'.

2.) In the quick-fix, set 'VideoPlayer.CurrentState' back to 'Closed' in between calls.

3.) Some other thing that mimics what the first click is doing.

Of course, both of my ideas involve changing a read-only variable. Which is where I'm getting stuck. I'll include the .xaml code for good measure, but I'm confident that it's the method 'SetSource' that's the root of my troubles:

```
<Grid x:Name="VideoViewerParentGrid" Background="DarkGreen" Height="{Binding VideoViewerParentGridHeight }" Width="{Binding VideoViewerParentGridWidth}">
    <MediaElement x:Name="VideoPlayer" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Stretch="Uniform"
                  Visibility="{Binding VideoVisibility, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" Tapped="VideoViewerClose_Tapped" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Name="Play_Button" Content="Play Video" FontSize="26" Tapped="playVideo_Tapped"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Width="180" Margin="0,80,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

---- UPDATE ----

Some more poking has revealed that on the first click 'VideoPlayer.CurrentState' never reaches the 'Playing' state, instead going from 'Opening' right back to 'Closed'. It does not do this on any subsequent clicks for as long as the program is running. Still investigating the cause of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short version, this issue is fixed by changing this:

```
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await videoFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
  VideoPlayer.SetSource(fileStream, videoFile.ContentType);
}
```

...to be this:

```
IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await videoFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
VideoPlayer.SetSource(fileStream, videoFile.ContentType);
```

Longer version, my code was failing because of the error "mf_media_engine_err_src_not_supported hresult - 0xc00d36c4", which was closing my MediaElement instead of playing it. This was happening because when I left the 'using' block of code the 'IRandomAccessStream' would close in the middle of my reading of the file. I'm not 100% clear why it gets through the whole thing after the first run of the code, but at least it now works reliably.

I've also got to give credit where credit is due, and I found this answer here: [Windows 8 app - MediaElement not playing ".wmv" files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202386/windows-8-app-mediaelement-not-playing-wmv-files)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "await" keyword. Do this:-

```
await setUpVideo();
```

Comment: I added it, but unfortunately there was no change whatsoever how it works.