# 'MediaElement.CurrentState' is changing to 'Closed' for unknown reasons

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, mediaelement

My program is supposed to play a video when the user taps the 'Play' button. However, the very first tap of 'Play' does nothing.

The code for this is pretty simple, it simply calls 'SetSource' on my MediaElement, VideoPlayer, and then plays:

```
private async void playVideo_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await setUpVideo();
    VideoPlayer.Play();
}
```

I've been through 'setUpVideo()' numerous times and everything there works like it should, it only calls 'VideoPlayer.SetSource()' after making sure the file exists. It wasn't until I threw in a method to monitor the state of 'VideoPlayer.CurrentState' that I realized the problem:

```
public VideoViewer()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    VideoPlayer.CurrentStateChanged += VideoPlayer_CurrentStateChanged;
}

void VideoPlayer_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var foo = VideoPlayer.CurrentState;
}
```

If I check the value of 'foo' while my code runs I see that on the first tap (and only the first tap) 'VideoPlayer.CurrentState' changes to 'Opening' after 'playVideo_Tapped()' is finished and then changes back to 'Closed'! Every tap thereafter will follow the correct progression of 'Opening' to 'Playing' and then 'Paused', but the first tap always closes. Why is this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem was in 'setUpVideo()' after all. Woops.

Short version, this issue is fixed by changing a piece of code in 'setUpVideo()' from this:

```
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await videoFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
  VideoPlayer.SetSource(fileStream, videoFile.ContentType);
}
```

...to this:

```
IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await videoFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
VideoPlayer.SetSource(fileStream, videoFile.ContentType);
```

Longer version, my code was failing because of the error "mf_media_engine_err_src_not_supported hresult - 0xc00d36c4", which was closing my MediaElement instead of playing it. This was happening because when I left the 'using' block of code the 'IRandomAccessStream' would close in the middle of my reading of the file. I'm not 100% clear why it gets through the whole thing after the first run of the code, but at least it now works reliably.

I've also got to give credit where credit is due, and I found this answer here: [Windows 8 app - MediaElement not playing ".wmv" files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202386/windows-8-app-mediaelement-not-playing-wmv-files)